# How to sum a date's value AND neighboring values above

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

[image: Sample Data With Desired Results Of Code]Im looking to add up the sum of daily data with the previous days. For example, in the picture, I want to look at 17-AUG and I get a sum of 35. That is, it sums A3: A10. It starts at A10 because that is 17-AUG, then all the values above it. Looking at 11-AUG, the result is three because it sums up only A3: A4 (1+2).

At first, I thought something like this would work,
=SUMIF($B$3:$B$13, D3>=$A$3:$A$13), but this always returned FALSE.
How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, =SUMIF($A$3:$A$13, "<="&E3, $B$3:$B$13), try it.  This $ sign is so that the range of dates and values do not change as you copy the formula.